# Angular translate service: HTML tags in string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have an `KEY` which contains a string with a HTML tag: `Foo <strong>bar</strong>` and I'm using the angular translate service:

```
$translate('KEY').then(function(text) {
    $scope.text = text;
});
```

As output I get `Foo <strong>bar</strong>`, but I want to get 'Foo **bar**'. Is there are way to get this with the translate service?

I already set the sanitize strategy to `sanitize`, but even this does not help. I know that it works with the translate directive but it doesn't fit to my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ngBindHtml directive:

```
<div ng-bind-html="text"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(param);`

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security